# Selenium RC and IE Script Error - Access is denied

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-rc

Another IE6 Script error seeming to popup at random occassions during my TestNG - Java - Selenium RC test runs.

Any clues to what maybe the root cause of this type of errors?

[image: Screenshot: IE Access Denied Script Error]

Answer (score 0):

Probably would be worth to know that is happening at the line that is indicated by the error popup. IE JS interpreter is giving from time to time really strange errors.

Please consider installing the debugger and then provide the part of code that is giving the error.

Below a link on how to install the script debugger for IE. Otherwise you can install Visual Studio which will do the same job.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the junk data from the "Temp" folder,and your problem would be solved.